# Is the quantity $\frac{(b^{\alpha+1}-a^{\alpha+1})(b^{1-\alpha}-a^{1-\alpha})}{(b-a)^2}$ bounded?

Tags: inequality

I'd like to know whether the following inequality holds:

> If $0<\alpha<1$, there is a constant $C_\alpha>0$, depending only on $\alpha$, that $\frac{(b^{\alpha+1}-a^{\alpha+1})(b^{1-\alpha}-a^{1-\alpha})}{(b-a)^2}\leq C_\alpha$ for any $a,b>0$ with $a<b$.

Intuitively, I think that the above inequality is true, considering that the fast-growing property of $(b^{\alpha+1}-a^{\alpha+1})$ is cancelled by slower growth of $(b^{1-\alpha}-a^{1-\alpha})$. However, I'm having difficulty figuring out the rigorous proof.

Trivially it is true for $\alpha=0,1$. Hence, if the above inequality is true for some $\alpha\in (0,1)$, then I wonder what is the range of $\alpha$ such that the desired inequality holds. I'd like it to hold for at least $\alpha=\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the numerator and denominator by $a^2=a^{\alpha+1} a^{1-\alpha}$ and then take $b/a=x$.

So your expression reduces to
$$
\frac{(x^{\alpha+1}-1)(x^{1-\alpha}-1)}{(x-1)^2}.
$$

Now, either you can take the derivative with respect to $x$, which can become messy, or you can expand the bracket in the numerator to get,

$$
\frac{x^2 - x(x^\alpha + x^{-\alpha}) + 1}{(x-1)^2}.
$$

Since $x^\alpha + x^{-\alpha} \geq 2$, we can see that the numerator is always smaller than the denominator. So your expression is bounded above by $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Krishnarjun's answer, I found another solution, which does not require to use derivatives.

According to Krishnarjun's hint, the inequality I'd like to find can be reduced to find an upper bound of the function $f(x)=\frac{(x^{1-\alpha}-1)(x^{1+\alpha}-1)}{(x-1)^2}$ for $x>1$. Clearly it is continuous on the interval $(1,\infty)$, and

$$ \lim_{x\to 1+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1+}\frac{x^{1-\alpha}-1}{x-1}\cdot\frac{x^{1+\alpha}-1}{x-1}= (1-\alpha)(1+\alpha),$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1.$$

Combining these two results and the continuity of $f$, we conclude that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: I did not use derivatives in my answer. My first thought was to use the derivative but then I realized that expanding the brackets would easily do the trick. Cheers.